How can I get the logs of applications that are in the foreground of each windows monitor in python
Good afternoon, I would like to know if it is possible for me to obtain the logs of the applications that each monitor is showing
Example of expected log
The foreground applications are: views.py - sk-access-control-ai - Visual Studio Code and yGetWindow Docs - Google Chrome

if the screens were like this:

If it were something like this example it would be incredible because I'm making a monitoring webapp.
What I've already tested
I've already tried using some libraries like win32, pygetwindow and psutil.
Here is an example of the code I am using now, but it does not work for the reasons I will describe below
import win32gui
def get_window_titles():
   
    window_titles = []
    try:
       
        def enum_window_titles(hwnd, window_titles):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
                if window_title:
                    window_titles.append(window_title)

        win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_window_titles, window_titles)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting window titles: {e}")
    return window_titles[:2] # This number is replaced by the number of existing monitors

# Getting and printing window titles
window_titles = get_window_titles()
for title in window_titles:
    print("Foreground applications are: " + title)

The reasons for this code not working are as follows:
what I have is something like (output):
The foreground applications are: views.py - sk-access-control-ai - Visual Studio Code
The foreground applications are: PyGetWindow Docs - Google Chrome

which takes the 2 applications in the foreground depending on the number of monitors, if there were 3 it would take the 3 applications in the foreground,
but even if there is none in the foreground and we are in the work environment or with one of the monitors on the work screen, it will associate that as there are 2 monitors it will give 2 different logs and not just 1 as expected.

Do you just want to join them like "and".join(window_titles)?

No, it's not just that, sorry if I sent that message, my problem is that I'm not able to specifically search for the applications that are being shown on the monitors, but rather that logs me according to which ones are in the foreground. others, because for example, if I have 2 monitors connected, one is in vscode and the other is on the desktop, but Google Chrome is running behind vscode, it gives me as output vscode and google chrome, when in fact it would be vscode and work environment, or even vscode and "empty"

In your example screenshot, Chrome is visible - do you only want the focused window? For something more manual, you could use GetWindowRect() to list the position of each window and then do math to see where they are or whether the top one overlaps

This wouldn't be a bad idea, but I've now tested using GetWindowsRect but I don't think it would be the best option for the logs, as I would have to give them the right positions.
I want the 2 focus windows to be the ones on each monitor, so the log would be "The foreground applications are: views.py - sk-access-control-ai - Visual Studio Code and yGetWindow Docs - Google Chrome" , So I have 2 monitors and each one has a program in the foreground

Windows generally only care about their position, and not which monitor they are on (for example, you can stretch a single window across multiple monitors). Your current code is just listing the first two windows in top to bottom order - the same order as the alt+tab list, right? If you want one entry for each monitor, you will have to filter by their positions. Something like screen.allScreens to return the monitor positions may be helpful?

not always as if it were alt tab, because let's imagine that I have 5 windows one overlapping the others on the 2nd monitor and on the 1st I only have one, if I alt tab these 5 windows will appear, where I actually want the monitor application 1, and I'll want the one on top of monitor 2, but I liked your way of thinking and I'll think about some approach like that, thank u for ur time
